# Create dynamic url in codeigniter by dynamic controller and model with category and its subcategory

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to create controller by which we can show category and sub category in url

Ex :

If we add in database category like : mac and add in database subcategory like : macbook

and inside of this we add the post like : How to Solve Microphone Issue in Macbook

So url should be create :
http://example.com/mac/macbook/microphone-issue-in-macbook/

Show to create dynamic this in Codeigniter

Comment: i think you want like this..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862311/arrange-category-and-subcategory-in-php-and-codeigniter/32862886#32862886

Answer (score 1):

You should store the slugs in database table, in a column called slug, then find a post with the slug, like this:

```
public function view($slug)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug), 1);
}
```